# Spring + Thymeleaf show last two elements from list

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using MVC and send from Controller to Model a List of elements.

How can I wrote only last 2 elements from the List ?

Like this I print ALL elements from the List...

```
<h2>NEWS</h2>
<ul>
  <li th:each="newsObject : ${news}">
    <small class="date"> <div th:text="${newsObject.getDate()}"/></small>
    <p th:text="${newsObject.getMessage()}"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For example I have 10 News in list, like:

```
   id|  date    | message
    1 2000-10-12 Something
    2 1999-11-12 Other message
    .
    .
    .
    9 2015-11-26 Oldest
    10 2015-11-27 The hotest
```

What I should do in `.html` file using Thymeleaf to achieve the "hotest" news ?
Like in example below:

```
 2015-11-27 The hotest
 2015-11-26 Oldest
```

I need only 2 elements. It's possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Iteration Status](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) along with a `th:if`.

Once you define the iteration status variable in the `th:each`, you can access `index` and `size` which will give you the current position, and total length of the list. The `th:if` can then be used to only include the last 2 elements:

```
<li th:each="newsObject, iterStat : ${news}" th:if="${iterStat.index >= iterStat.size-2}">
    ... contents go here ...
</li>
```